# How to adjust (not 100% override) existing eslint rule's configuration coming from config I extend?

Tags: eslint

My project's eslint config extends from airbnb:

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: {
    project: "./tsconfig.eslint.json",
  },
  plugins: ["@typescript-eslint"],
  extends: [
    "airbnb-base",
    "airbnb-typescript/base"
  ]
};
```

I would like to slightly adjust the [`import/no-extraneous-dependencies`](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/v2.26.0/docs/rules/no-extraneous-dependencies.md) rule which is [already configured with airbnb config](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/blob/eslint-config-airbnb-v19.0.4/packages/eslint-config-airbnb-base/rules/imports.js#L71-L97).

I am interested in adding one more file to allowed for `devDependencies` imports:

```js
rules: {
  "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": [
    "error",
    {
      devDependencies: ["vitest.config.ts"],
    },
  ],
},
```

If I do like above, then I completely overwrite the list in `'import/no-extraneous-dependencies'[1].devDependencies` and the configuration I inherited from airbnb gets lost. How to add one more file to `devDependencies` list instead of completely overwriting the rule's configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like configurations of the single rule from different configs do not get somehow merged. So, if the last config which configured `import/no-extraneous-dependencies` rule was `airbnb-typescript/base`, then I just need to import it and adjust it as needed.

Below is the solution for my case:

```js
const airbnb = require("eslint-config-airbnb-typescript/lib/shared");

const airbnbNoExtraDepsRule = airbnb.rules["import/no-extraneous-dependencies"];
airbnbNoExtraDepsRule[1].devDependencies.push("vitest.config.ts");

module.exports = {
  extends: ["airbnb-base", "prettier"],
  rules: {
    "import/no-commonjs": "on",
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": airbnbNoExtraDepsRule,
  }
};
```